# Heroku not updating config vars with react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, heroku, environment-variables

I deployed the react app on Heroku and I have a problem with Config Vars(env variables). I changed them in settings and they are not updating.

When sending XHR request I got an error `Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` because of the old one env variable which was staring with HTTP and I decided to change it to HTTPS. The Env variable is not updating.

```
REACT_APP_SERVER1="https://my-app.herokuapp.com"
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you sure the server is hosted on https?

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar problem with a NodeJS mongoDB app.

Comment: The problem was port which node js listened. Try to figure out if something is not okay with your ports and env variables on Heroku.